# How to setup multiple site in live server?

Tags: php, apache, server

I had been asked a question that, Is it possible to setup multiple site on live server?

I was confused. I had an idea about local server.In local server you can do with making entries in machine host file.

Please anyone guide me about this.

Comment: SO is not there to search guides for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, it works exactly the same as on local server but instead of editing hosts file you have DNS server, which can translate domains to IP adresses. Next, Apache server splits requests into domains by `Host` header in HTTP request.

Comment: thanks kamil,your answaser has clear my mind out of way.